# Flask - How to download a filename with a . dot prefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, download

I have a flask app and am trying to set up a download where the file that is downloaded starts with a "." (dot, or period).  The code is listed below, but I have tried several methods, each simply removes the "dot" at the beginning.  I feel like this should be simple, but I am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
@app.route('/.blah.auth', methods=['GET'])
def downloadBlahAuth(roleLevel = app.config["PAGE_ROLE_LEVELS"][".blah.auth"]):
  """
  filePath = os.path.join(app.config["DOWNLOADS_FOLDER"], ".blah.auth");
  theFile = open(filePath, "r")
  fileText = theFile.read()
  theFile.close()

  strIO = StringIO.StringIO()
  strIO.write(fileText)
  strIO.seek(0)
  return send_file(strIO, attachment_filename=".blah.auth", as_attachment=True)
  """
  fileName = ".blah.auth"
  return send_from_directory(directory=app.config["DOWNLOADS_FOLDER"], filename=fileName)
```

Comment: Hey all, does anyone have an answer for this?  Or an explanation why it's not possible if so?  Thanks!